# Where clause to exclude specific email domains

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a list of `emails` and I want to write a where statement, to exclude rows that **only** contain the email domains `%@icloud.com` or `%@mac.com`

> For example, `emails` list looks like this:

abc@gmail.com; 123@hotmail.com

123@outlook.com; abc@icloud.com

123@icloud.com;

123@icloud.com; abc@mac.com

> the desired output should look like this:

abc@gmail.com; 123@hotmail.com

123@outlook.com; abc@icloud.com *(this row should be returned because it also contains '@outlook.com' which isn't on my exclude list)*

Comment: Don't store multiple values as comma delimited strings in relational databases. Your table should have a new row for each user/email pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer a more vanilla approach to Simeon's solution

```
where replace(replace(col,'@icloud.com',''), '@mac.com','') like '%@%'
```

In Snowflake, the replacement string is optional, which shortens that to

```
where replace(replace(col,'@icloud.com'), '@mac.com') like '%@%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Given negative lookaheads are not supported, away to achieve that is two remove the unwanted matched, and then look for an "any email left" match:

```
SELECT column1
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '@((icloud)|(mac))\\.com', '') as cleaned
    ,REGEXP_LIKE(cleaned, '.*@.*\\.com.*') as logic
FROM VALUES
('abc@gmail.com; 123@hotmail.com'),
('123@outlook.com; abc@icloud.com'),
('123@icloud.com;'),
('123@icloud.com; abc@mac.com');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | CLEANED | LOGIC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com; 123@hotmail.com | abc@gmail.com; 123@hotmail.com | TRUE |
| 123@outlook.com; abc@icloud.com | 123@outlook.com; abc | TRUE |
| 123@icloud.com; | 123; | FALSE |
| 123@icloud.com; abc@mac.com | 123; abc | FALSE |

which can be merged into one line:

```
,REGEXP_LIKE(REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '@((icloud)|(mac))\\.com'), '.*@.*\\.com.*') as logic
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on string split approach in SQL server, using [`split_to_table`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) function, you probably have to tweak the syntax a little:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
    select *
    from split_to_table(t.emails, ';') as sv
    where sv.value not like '%@icloud.com'
    and sv.value not like '%@mac.com'
)
```